# How to import java.awt.Robot & java.awt.event.KeyEvent in python binding for selenium and its sample usage

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, popupwindow, python-bindings

Setup :python bindings for selenium 2.45.0 ,IEserver driver2.45.0(x86),python 2.7.9 ,window 7 64 bit

Problem:Trying to handle security based windows popup(OS) in a web application(input password and click ok) .

Tried
1. alert handling like this work , able to enter password

```
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
alert.send_keys("1246545")
```

but now following doesn't work , not able to click ok or press ENETER

```
alert.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
alert.send_keys("1246545"+Keys.ENTER)
```

2.Autoit , dont want to use it , will be last option

3.seen some solution like using Robot class

```
Robot rb =new Robot();
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

I am new to java , dont know how to import these packages in python bindings  , this is how they do in selenium.

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
```

want to know how to import above pacakages in python bindings for selenium , some working examples are

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative approach, you may like to use this special URL format to pass the credentials in the HTTP Authorization header.

**http://username:password@example.com/**

Comment: thats not option for me , its pki authentication  , so password cannot be passed along with url